# Cambiar paleta de colores estándar por la de Office 2007-2010

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Buen día.

Alguien podría decirme si hay una forma sencilla de cambiar la paleta de colores estándar en Excel y Word mediante código vba para seleccionar la paleta de Office 2007-2010?

Gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

En excel, tienes que incluir esta línea de código:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ( _
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Document Themes 16\Theme Colors\Office 2007 - 2010.xml" _
    )
```

Como ves, los temas están guardados en un directorio de tu computadora, y son archivos *.xml. Si exploras ese directorio, verás que hay muchos temas y puedes elegir cualquiera de ellos.

Y para cambiar el tema en word, es algo diferente. tienes que usar:

```
ActiveDocument.ApplyTheme "tema nnn"
```

La cadena de texto tiene dos partes, y ha de usarla así:

`tema`  Nombre de la carpeta que contiene los datos del tema solicitado. (La ubicación predeterminada de las carpetas de datos de tema es C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Themes) Debe usar el nombre de carpeta para el tema en lugar del nombre para mostrar que aparece en el cuadro de diálogo Tema.

`nnn`   Cadena de tres dígitos que indica las opciones de formato del tema que se desea activar (1 para activar, 0 para desactivar). Los dígitos corresponden a las casillas Colores vívidos, Gráficos activos e Imagen de fondo del cuadro de diálogo Tema. Si se omite esta cadena, el valor predeterminado de nnn es "011" (se activa Gráficos activos e Imagen de fondo).

Le dejo un enlace a la documentación de Office Word donde explica este método:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/word.document.applytheme

Comment: Muy amable, José Luis. Funciona perfectamente en Excel, pero no en Word. Conoces por casualidad cómo debo escribirlo en Word? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te lo busco, dame unos minutos. Mientras, si te ha sido útil la respuesta, puedes aceptarla, pls.

Comment: Edito la respuesta para añadir lo relativo a Word, que es diferente, en efecto.

Comment: Tras mucho rebuscar he encontrado de pasada la solución en otra pregunta de esta página en inglés: `ActiveDocument.DocumentTheme.ThemeColorScheme.Load "ruta"`

Comment: Por otro lado creo que su respuesta para Word no es lo que busco, porque no cambia la paleta de colores sino el tema. Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Un saludo.